# ProgressDrawable setColorFilter doesn't work in Nexus 5

Tags: android, colorfilter, layerdrawable

I have a `RatingBar` :

```
<RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="0.75"
        android:isIndicator="false"
        android:scaleY="0.75"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        android:numStars="5" />
```

and I'm using a color filter to make the rating bar stars pink in color like so:

```
    ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    Drawable progressDrawable = ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
    if (progressDrawable instanceof  LayerDrawable) {
        LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) progressDrawable;
        stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorSecondary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorSecondary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorSecondary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
```

This works fine in all phones except the Nexus 5 ( Android version 6.0 ) where the 5 stars are all pink, but filled by default. Even when I click on the stars, they don't change color, all 5 remain filled.

However when I do `ratingBar.getRating()`, it returns the rating of where my user has touched the rating bar which means it's working, just the color filter is malfunctioning.

If I remove the color filter, the `RatingBar` works fine with the default colors.

Can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry that it's not the answer, but what's driving the requirement setting it from code ? And .setProgressDrawable should work if it's defined correctly

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/progress_start"
                android:endColor="@color/progress_end"
                android:angle="270" 
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

And need more detail about progress bar's colors filters check this link : http://ambracode.com/index/show/14297

Comment: It wasn't quite what I was looking for but since it's a phone specific thing, I don't know how to solve it myself. I've switched to XML. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Use below one instead of `getProgressDrawable()` in android 6.0

```
LayerDrawable ldRating = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
ldRating.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_empty_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
ldRating.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_half_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
ldRating.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_full_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```